# Problem adding song with user_playlist_add_tracks (Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None)

Tags: python, json, spotify, spotipy

I recently tested an app in Github because I want to create a playlist of song with a list of artists. Here is the link of the project : https://github.com/streadgold/FestivalPlaylistMaker

Credentials are good, redirect URI seems to be good also. I've tested with multiple artists, then 20 (=100 songs if there is a Spotify song's limit), then just 1 but I've the same error. Here is the log I get when I launch my app :

```
adding  1WsHKAuN9vDthcmimdqqaY Your Mind
adding  34I6QYP9yREZnvVZvDIo1u Legend
adding  1kMObCQiYe5opqybH7ZNPD Rave - Remix
adding  2zDCZ8jY4kjuUZbVROHaZj Your Mind - Radio Edit
adding  0I7ggM44AhOpWIZCM02HtP In From The Night - Adam Beyer & Wehbba Remix
adding song  0
Adding song failed:
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
adding song  1
Adding song failed:
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
adding song  2
Adding song failed:
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
adding song  3
Adding song failed:
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
adding song  4
Adding song failed:
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
Playlist Complete!
```

I don't understand because I have good parameters and my songs are in array :

```
['1WsHKAuN9vDthcmimdqqaY', '34I6QYP9yREZnvVZvDIo1', '1kMObCQiYe5opqybH7ZNPD', '2zDCZ8jY4kjuUZbVROHaZj', '0I7ggM44AhOpWIZCM02HtP']
```

The problem append when I want to add each song one by one :

```
user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks[:1], position=None)
```

That cause this error with "**reason: None**" :

```
http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
```

Any idea for this problem ? Could you help me please ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It is good information to run experience it. Thanks!
I tested it works well on windows. It added 778 songs into existing my playlist. Only 9 songs (62,141,224,379,395,522,669,714,764) failed with 400 error . it means invalid track (not exist song), example : https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/1qRJWYZlXrycHQs3KkfCg
So I can't reproduce your problem (from song 0 to 4 - 400 error).

Comment: you needs change `redirect_uri` line 29 at main.py with your value.

Comment: Why are you using a deprecated API ```user_playlist_add_tracks()```? Anyway your did wrong in ```tracks.append(str(t['id'].strip('u')))```. Change it like ```tracks.append(t['id'])```. Also do like ```results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks[0])``` and remove the unused ```index```.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I already got the same error after editing the tracks array. I've changed the URI by another, and it seems to be exactly the same... If it works on Windows, I think that the problem could probably come from my environment : WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. Probably a redirect_uri connection problem when the app wants to communicate outside my WSL ?

Answer (score 0):

`user_playlist_add_tracks()` is deprecated. Use `playlist_add_items(playlist_id, items, position=None)` instead.
Note: `items` has to be a list of `["URIs"]`, so lines 38 and 39 have to be:

```
tracks.append(str(t['uri'])
print('adding ', t['uri'], t['name'])
```

And line 44:

```
results = sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id, tracks[:1], position=None)
```

Also, I recommend you to add the `playlist-modify-private` scope on line 28:

```
scope = 'playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'
```